# Q: Clarification on Subset, Subspace, Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Given: $$V = P^4$$ That is, $V$ is the set of all polynomials in $x$ of degree at most four.

If $S = \{1+x^2, x^3, 2x^3\}$

Can: $$S \subset V \space\space ?$$
I would say yes based strictly on the definition of subsets.

**Questions:**

Is $\text{span}(S)$ a subspace of $V$?

I understand that in order to be a subspace, the subset needs to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Given this, is $S$ also a subspace of $V$? Because you will never leave the bounds of $V$?

Is $S$ a basis of $V$?

I would say no, since not only is $S$ not linearly independent, it does not span $V$. That is, it is missing terms like $x$ and $x^4$.

Can you make a basis by including elements of $S$ + additional terms? Or should the basis simply be $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4\}$?

If you can make a basis by including elements of $S$, would the elements be $\{1+x^2, x^3\} \cup \space \{1, x, x^4\}$?

Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: What do you mean by S?

Comment: There are a number of strange and incorrect wordings here.  First, I suspect you mean to have $V$ be the set of all polynomials in $x$ of degree *at most* four (*as opposed to exactly four*).  Next, I suspect that if you wish for $S$ to be a set of just the three vectors as written, then you want to ask if the *span* of $S$ is a subspace of $V$, not $S$ itself.  We can then ask if the *set* $S$ is a basis for the *span* of $S$, as opposed to being a basis for $V$.  Of course, it will be a basis for neither in this example.

Comment: S is the set $\{1+x^2, x^3, 2x^3\}$

Comment: Since we know $V$ is five-dimensional, obviously a three element set cannot be a basis for it, that didn't even need to be checked any further.  Also obviously the elements in $S$ aren't linearly independent as $x^3$ and $2x^3$ are very clearly multiples of one another.  Now, on to your results... yes, one of the many different bases for $V$ could be $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ and this is the most common one, but it could also have been $\{1,x,1+x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ as you suggest or any of the infinitely many other choices if you desire having elements of $S$ in your basis for $V$

Comment: @JMoravitz I modified the question to follow your comments, as those are indeed what I was asking. If $S$ is given as is, the $span$ of S is always a subspace of V, but $S$ by itself is not, correct?

Comment: Correct.  $S$ itself is not a subspace.  A subspace would need to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but clearly $(1+x^2)+x^3$ is not an element of $S$ despite each of $(1+x^2)$ and $x^3$ being elements of $S$.  Similarly, $42\times x^3$ is not an element of $S$ despite $42$ being in our scalar field and $x^3$ being in $S$.  These may be elements of $V$, but we aren't talking about $V$ right now, we're talking about $S$.  It is clear to see that with an infinite scalar field, any subspace of dimension greater than zero will have infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- $S$ is a subset of V but not a subspace (the span of $S$ is a subspace)
- $S$ can't be a basis of $V$ because a basis must contain exactly $5$ linearly independent elements
- yes, including $1$, $x^4$ and $x$ and eliminating $x^3$ or $2x^3$ it becomes a basis

Comment: is $S$ not a subspace because it violates addition/scalar multiplication on the defined vectors? I'm struggling with visualizing this. @JMoravitz answered this above, thank you both!

Comment: @Clark S is a finite set of vecrors therefore can't be a subspace, the set of all the linear combination of the elements of S (that is the span) is a subpace.